# How to dedupe stringified jsons on the key on postgres table?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table in postgres like:

```
CREATE TABLE data (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    values varchar
);

INSERT INTO data (values) VALUES
    ('k1=v1&k2=v2&k3=v3&k1=v4'),
    ('k2=v1&k2=v2&k3=v1&k2=v4&k3=v4')
    ;
```

Each row in `values` contains a string which is a k:v pair delimited by &. The field may contain any integer number of values, like `NULL`, or `k1=v1&...kN=vN`. I want to return a new column, which contains a deduped variant of `values`.

The deduping should occur on the key, and the first (leftmost) instance of the key should be kept. So in my example data, the output would be:

| id | values | values_d |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | k1=v1&k2=v2&k3=v3&k1=v4 | k1=v1&k2=v2&k3=v3 |
| 2 | k2=v1&k2=v2&k3=v1=k2=v4&k3=v4 | k2=v1&k3=v1 |

My approach so far has been to convert the column into a jsonb object to rely on jsonb's deduping. But jsonb dedupes keep the righmost elements, and my efforts to invert arrays have screwed up indices and I can't resolve.

### **MY ATTEMPT:**

```
drop view if exists alan_1 cascade;
create view alan_1 as (
 SELECT
        values,
         regexp_split_to_array(values, '[=&]') AS kv_parts,
        generate_series(1, array_length(regexp_split_to_array(values, '[=&]'), 1), 2) AS idx
    FROM data
                      );


select * from alan_1;


drop view if exists alan_2 cascade;
create view alan_2 as
(

    SELECT
    values
    ,idx
        ,ARRAY(
        SELECT
            CASE
                WHEN i % 2 = 0 THEN kv_parts[i - 1]
                ELSE kv_parts[i + 1]
            END
        FROM generate_series(1, array_length(kv_parts, 1)) AS i
    ) AS kv_parts_r
    , kv_parts

    from alan_1

);

select * from alan_2;



drop view if exists alan_3 cascade;
create view alan_3 as
(
SELECT *,
       ARRAY(
               SELECT kv_parts_r[i]
               FROM generate_series(array_length(kv_parts_r, 1), 1, -1) AS i
           ) AS reversed_array
FROM alan_2
    );

select * from alan_3;



drop view if exists alan_4 cascade;
create view alan_4 as (
SELECT
    values,
    json_object_agg(
        reversed_array[idx], reversed_array[idx + 1]
    ) AS distinct_key_values
FROM alan_3
GROUP BY values
);

select * from alan_4;
```

### **EDIT**

After playing around more I found *a* solution. By no means is it amazing, but it works. The general idea is:

1. convert string to array splittting on the delimeter between `k=v` pairs
2. reverse array
3. convert array to jsonb object (deduping occurs here). It saves the rightmost element in each dupe, which is logically the leftmost of the original string due to reversing in step 2.
4. convert jsonb back to string

```
drop view if exists v_1 cascade;
create view v_1 as (
SELECT
    values,
     string_to_array(values, '&') as a
from data);
select * from v_1;


drop view if exists v_2 cascade;
create view v_2 as (
SELECT
    values,
    a,
    ARRAY(SELECT a[i] FROM generate_subscripts(a, 1) AS i ORDER BY i DESC) AS reverse
FROM v_1);



drop view if exists v_3 cascade;
create view v_3 as
(
select values, reverse, array_to_string(reverse, '&') AS reversed_values
from v_2
    );

drop view if exists v_4 cascade;
create view v_4 as(

    SELECT
    values,
    jsonb_object_agg(kv_key, kv_value) AS json_data
FROM (
    SELECT
        values,
        reversed_values,
        kv_pair,
        split_part(kv_pair, '=', 1) AS kv_key,
        split_part(kv_pair, '=', 2) AS kv_value
    FROM v_3
    CROSS JOIN LATERAL regexp_split_to_table(reversed_values, '&') AS kv_pair
) AS extracted_kv_pairs
GROUP BY values);


select * from v_4;

SELECT
    json_data,
    string_agg(concat_ws('=', key, value), '&') AS concatenated_string
FROM v_4,
LATERAL jsonb_each_text(json_data)
GROUP BY json_data;
```

Comment: I would avoid using `json(b)` for this. Rather, use a subquery where you can `GROUP BY` or `SELECT DISTINCT ON` with an `ORDER BY index`

Comment: Does it have to be done using SQL? This would be trivial to achieve in app code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to manipulate arrays to do this.  Split to a table with ordinality and then use `distinct on` to keep only the first instance of the key:

```
with expand as (
  select distinct on (d.id, split_part(r.kv, '=', 1)) 
         d.id, d.values,
         split_part(r.kv, '=', 1) as k, 
         split_part(r.kv, '=', 2) as v
    from data d
         cross join lateral regexp_split_to_table(d.values, '&') 
                              with ordinality r(kv, i)
   order by id, k, r.i
)
select id, values, string_agg(concat(k, '=', v), '&') as values_d
  from expand
 group by id, values;
```

[Working fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/osVMuNX3)

Comment: Thanks @Mike! This is really slick. Much faster than the solution I ended up with!